# how to copy the value of a text field , remove symbols and spaces and placed a hyphen instead?

Tags: jquery

I have two text fields one is called business_name and another is called slug. I have it so that when a person types in a business name into the designated field the value is copied into the slug field. I also want the value that is coming into the slug field to remove everything but leave letters and numbers and to replace spaces with a hypen. This is what i have currently, firebug wont show me any errors so i dont know what im doing wrong

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var business_name = '';
    $("#business_name").bind('keypress', function() {
        business_name = $(this).val();
        business_name.replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]\s+/g', '-').toLowerCase();
        $("#slug").val(business_name);

    });
});
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong for what you've described. It should be `/\s+|[^A-Za-z0-9]/g` or something similar. Without the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: `string.replace` doesn't mutate a string, it creates a new one.

Second problem: your regex would match all the characters, you only want to match anything that isn't a letter or number or a space and remove it.

Third problem: regexes aren't strings. They don't need to be enclosed in quotes

something like:

```
business_name = business_name.replace(/\s+/g,'-').toLowerCase();             // replace spaces
business_name = business_name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g,'');                 // remove other characters
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghw6c/4/

Comment: I thinks this is the correct answer. Just two things: `/\s+/g` and maybe `/[^\w-]/g`.

Comment: @azeós: Agreed on `\s+` unless the OP wants double spaces replaced with double `--`, which I doubt. In the second case `\w` includes underscores in at least some implementations of regex, so it wouldn't remove them. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): *Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]*

Comment: Good to know Matt, I didn't knew that \w may include underscores.

Comment: i gotta catchup on regex, i wish it was easier :p

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here - when you call replace don't put quote around the regex.  You want something of the form:

```
business_name.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]\s+/g, '-')
```

Also, it doesn't replace in value in the original string - it returns a new string with the replaced text.  So when you set the value of #slug you're still looking at the original value.

The regex you had was also not doing quite what you intended, so I've changed it to first strip out anything that is not a letter, number or white-space, and then it converts any white-space to a dash.

You could change your slug line to

```
        $("#slug").val(business_name.toLowerCase().replace(/![a-z0-9\s]/g, '').replace(/\s/, '-'));
```

I have forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/smC4k/)

Comment: oh i got it thanks, i setup a jsfiddle and noticed when i put a space it does a backspace and removes some of my text. if you try to type something and add spaces you'll see what i mean. is that the default state of what .replace() does? http://jsfiddle.net/ghw6c/2/

Comment: You still have quotes in the first case and in the second case, you don't get the result the OP wanted. You are replacing anything in the range of `a-zA-Z0-9` followed by a space with a `-` which means you lose a character.

Comment: @Matt - you're right on the first case.  I pasted his code instead of my fixed version.  I updated the second so that it first removes any non-letter/number/space, and then it replaces any space with a dash.

Comment: @SarmenHB - the regex expression needed tweaking.  I also get a better result when I run it on the `keyup` rather than `keypressed` event.  I posted my forked fiddle of yours in my answer.